# proto3 -> go with custom extensions resulting in imports to package ("google/protobuf") in go code

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am prototyping a meta model on top of proto3. To generate domain specific   boilerplate as the go proto3 extension syntax is ridiculously expressive. My domain proto files depend on `meta.proto` which contain the extensions.

I can compile the these to go. When including the `meta.proto` file the generated go ends up with the following include block:

```
import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
import fmt "fmt"
import math "math"
import google_protobuf "google/protobuf" <--- this import does not exist !!
```

My extension file has the following structure([based off this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions)):

```
syntax = "proto2";
package "...";

option go_package = "..."; 

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto"; <--- this causes the import

// message MyExtensionClass ...
// message MyExtensionField ...

extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
    optional MyExtensionClass class = 50000;
}

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
    optional MyExtensionField field = 50001;
}
```

I know the solution is likely very simple, the `google/protobuf` include is meant for C++ generation.

---

In my workspace the included package should be `"github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/descriptor"`

Comment: The `descriptor.proto` import is necessary when declaring custom options -- it's not just for C++ code generation. I don't know anything about Go, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poor mans solution. Not ideal, directing it to the relevant go import works:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/import google_protobuf \"google\/protobuf\"/import google_protobuf \"github.com\/golang\/protobuf\/protoc-gen-go\/descriptor\"/g' pkg/domain/proto/extensions/*.pb.go
```